# Java - New Instance not running new Instance Init Block

Tags: java, instance, block, init

It is my understanding that every time a class instance is created the instance init block runs. When I tried to test this, the instance init block ran for the first two created instances, but not the third.

Here's the code:

```
class ModuleInit {
    ModuleInit (int x) { System.out.println("1-arg const"); }
    ModuleInit () { System.out.println("No-arg const"); }
    static { System.out.println("First static init"); }
    { System.out.println("1st instance init"); }
    { System.out.println("2nd instance init"); }
    static { System.out.println("2nd static init"); }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ModuleInit();
        new ModuleInit(8);
    }
}
```

and here's the output:

```
First static init
2nd static init
1st instance init
2nd instance init
No-arg const
1st instance init
2nd instance init
1-arg const
               <---Missing instance init for ModuleInt(int x)?
```

I thought that when the new class instance with the int arg was created ( `ModuleInit(8)` ) that there should be another instance init block run. Can someone explain why this doesn't happen here?

Comment: `class ModuleInit` and constructor `Module4 (int x)`? Something is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance initialization blocks run as the first line within the constructors (that is, after the call to `super()` or `this()`, whether implicit or declared), so they are running before the constructor prints out its line:

```
First static init
2nd static init
1st instance init
2nd instance init
No-arg const
1st instance init  <---- They are right here...
2nd instance init  <---- They are right here...
1-arg const
```

This code would be equivalent:

```
class Module4 {
    Module4 (int x) { 
        System.out.println("1st instance init");
        System.out.println("2nd instance init");
        System.out.println("1-arg const"); 
    }
    Module4 () { 
        System.out.println("1st instance init");
        System.out.println("2nd instance init");            
        System.out.println("No-arg const"); 
    }
    static { System.out.println("First static init"); }
    //{ System.out.println("1st instance init"); }
    //{ System.out.println("2nd instance init"); }
    static { System.out.println("2nd static init"); }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ModuleInit();
        new ModuleInit(8);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I must have been thinking they ran after. Thanks!